# mac mini > apple tv: no audio except using itunes

Tags: audio, mac-mini, appletv, airplay

The 2014 Mac Mini is connected via ethernet cable to the latest-generation Apple TV, which in turn is connected to the TV via HDMI. Controlling the Mini via Screen Sharing, I start up iTunes, and am able to route its audio to the Apple TV and thence to the TV speakers. However, I'm unable to do this using Swinsian. (Swinsian is just another music player.)

ITunes does have its own widget next to the volume slider for speaker selection

1. Computer -- Great Room (plus sign)
2. Great Room -- Available (check mark and volume slider)

which Swinsian doesn't. However, in the menubar there is an "Airplay" widget. It has

1. Airplay: Great Room -- use as separate display
2. Airplay to -- Great Room

Number 1 is checked, and I can't switch it to #2.

I've rebooted/restarted each device. No luck.

How do I send audio from Mac Mini to Apple TV? I don't care one way or another whether the picture of the screen goes to the TV.

Comment: Try using AirPlay mirroring, this might pipe the audio of your entire system. With iTunes's own widget, it's iTunes itself doing the piping, so of course anything else won't go through.

Comment: @seaturtle - Thanks. I recently read (http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/01/stream-all-mac-system-audio-over-airplay-os-x/) that by option-clicking the _Sound_ menu in the menubar, I could select my Apple TV and route all sound there. The way I read the link, this is different than AirPlay mirroring. The terminology is confusing, but I'm now able to reliable send Swinsian (or any other sound) to my TV.

Comment: Fantastic, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

To route all sound from the Mac to the Apple TV, option-click the Sound menu in the menu bar on the Mac, and select Apple TV.

(Note: running Sierra)